# Given a list of positions in a matrix, get elements within radius r

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have a `n x n` binary matrix like

```
SeedRandom[1]; mat = RandomInteger[1, {9, 9}];
MatrixForm[mat]
```

[image]

I want to create partitions of radius r centered on the 1 elements.

If I have a border element at position {9, 1} and r = 3, as in the example above, I want to obtain `{{0,1,1}, {0,0,1},{1,1,1}}`

I know that `Position[mat , 1]` will give me the appropriate indices, but I haven't found in the documentation how to create partitions like the ones I want using `Take`, `Part` or `Partition`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `mat` provided:

```
f[r_, {i_, j_}] := Module[{ind = Tuples[Range[9], 2], pos},

  pos = Select[ind, ChessboardDistance[#, {i, j}] <= r - 1 &]; {pos, 
   Extract[mat, #] & /@ GatherBy[pos
     , First]}]
```

Visualizing:

```
 Manipulate[With[{res = f[r, p]},
  {ps, v} = res;
  Row[{ArrayPlot[ReplacePart[mat, Thread[ps -> Flatten@v + 2]], 
     ColorRules -> {2 -> Red, 3 -> Green}], ArrayPlot[v], 
    MatrixForm[v]}]], {{r, 3}, {2, 3, 4}}, {{p, {9, 1}}, 
  Tuples[Range[9], 2], PopupMenu}]
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent code!

Comment: @thils that is kind...I altered to stop repeated function calls in body. You approached general case...boundaries are always tricky...also constructive rather than my `select` approach will be better for very large arrays (i.e. finding 'neighbours' directly rather than filtering)...this was fun and I hope motivating...

Answer (score 4):

```
SeedRandom[1]; 

mat = RandomInteger[1, {9, 9}]; MatrixForm[mat]; 

MatrixForm[
 Flatten[Table[mat[[6 + i ;; -(4 - i), 1 ;; 3]], {i, 1, 3}], 1]]
```

General n,r

```
SeedRandom[1]; 
Manipulate[mat = RandomInteger[1, {n, n}]; MatrixForm[mat]; 
 MatrixForm[
  Flatten[Table[mat[[n - r + i ;; -(r + 1 - i), 1 ;; r]], {i, 1, r}], 
   1]], 
   {n, {9, 10, 20, 30}}, {r, {3, 4, 5}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also use  `Clip`

```
Transpose[Clip[pos + # & /@ {-r, r}, {1, n}]]
```

to get the positions within a radius `r` of `pos`.

```
Manipulate[SeedRandom[1]; mat = RandomInteger[1, {n, n}];
 Grid[MapIndexed[Setter[Dynamic@x, {#2}, #, ImageSize -> {30, 30}, 
   Appearance -> "Frameless"]&, Style[#, 20, Bold] & /@ # & /@ mat, {2}], 
  ItemStyle -> {Automatic, Automatic, 
   {Dynamic@Transpose[Clip[x + # & /@ {-r, r}, {1, n}]] -> Directive[Red,  Bold], 
   Dynamic[x] -> Green}}, Spacings -> {0, 0}], 
 Row[{Control@{{n, 9}, Range[8, 12], SetterBar}, 
   Control@{{r, 1}, Range[4], SetterBar}}, Spacer[20]], {mat, None}, Alignment -> Center]
```

[image]